# Reactor choosing a sink/processor

Tags: java, multithreading, project-reactor

I have the following use case:

Out of an application I am consuming with X threads some messages, where I have a Consumer implementation defined like that:

```
public interface Consumer {
     onMessage(Object message);
}
```

The problem is that Consumer is not a different instance per thread, but a single instance, as it is a Spring bean and we also expect it not to have side effects per single call of onMessage.

However, what I want to build is a duplicate message detection mechanism, which kind of looks like this:

```
public static <T> Flux<OcurrenceCache<T>> getExceedingRates(Flux<T> values, int maxHits, int bufferSize, Duration bufferTimeout) {
        return values.bufferTimeout(bufferSize, bufferTimeout)
            .map(vals -> {
                OcurrenceCache<T> occurrenceCache = new OcurrenceCache<>(maxHits);
                for (T value : vals) {
                    occurrenceCache.incrementNrOccurrences(value);
                }
                return occurrenceCache;
            });
}
```

Where basically from a Flux of values I am returning an occurrence cache with the elements that are encountered more than the max desired number of hits.

Naively, I can implement things like that:

```
public class MyConsumer implements Consumer {
    private final EmitterProcessor<Object> emitterProcessor;

    public MyConsumer(Integer maxHits, Integer bufferSize, Long timeoutMillis){
       this.emitterProcessor = EmitterProcessor.create();
       this.emitterProcessor
                .bufferTimeout(bufferSize, Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis))
                .subscribe(integers -> {
                    getExceedingRates(Flux.fromIterable(integers), maxHits, bufferSize, Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis))
                            .subscribe(integerOcurrenceCache -> {
                                System.out.println(integerOcurrenceCache.getExceedingValues());
                        });
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Object message){
        emitterProcessor.onNext(message); 
    }
}
```

However, this is far from optimal because I know that my messages from a specific thread will **NEVER** contain any the messages that came from another thread (they are pre-grouped as we use jms grouping and kinesis sharding). So, in a way, I'd like to use such a Processor that will:

- use the very same thread on which onMessage was called to kind of isolate the flux in such a way where values from it are isolated and not mixed up with the variables put from another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use thread local processors:

```
private final ThreadLocal<EmitterProcessor<Object>> emitterProcessorHolder = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> {
  EmitterProcessor<Object> processor = ...
  return processor;
});
...
@Override
public void onMessage(Object message){
  emitterProcessorHolder.get().onNext(message); 
}
```

Comment: Ye, not exactly what I was looking for but does the job of bridging the contexts. Another way would have been to use separate instances of my Consumers and use Flux.create on them as suggested here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1024 but in this case is probably easier to use the approach you suggested.